# How could i see all rows of my table in Dom?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have applied data table on my table and it is working fine. Please check CodePen's [link](https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/kXyazm)

```
$(document).ready(function() {



  var table = $('#example').DataTable({ 
        select: false,
        "columnDefs": [{
            className: "Name", 
            "targets":[0],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable":false
        }]
    });//End of create main table


  $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {

    alert(table.row( this ).data()[0]);

} );
});
```

but it is not loading all the rows(57) in Dom because of Pagination. i have a situation where i need the pagination and want all rows in dom too. Disabling the paging is not an option.

Comment: Are you looking for default pageSize or something ? https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength

Comment: @PraveenKumar S No. right now the tbody contains only 10 rows. Is there any way we can load all the rows in DOM without removing pagination?

Comment: the only method to achieve that is to fetch all the data at once and paginate in client side, instead of server side

Comment: You will probably need your own pagination and your own table mechanism because this is how datatable works. You will need to create datatable version that use hide/show instead of adding removing/DOM. Writing simple data table is good exercise. You can also for the library and modify it to use show/hide instead of adding/removing this will be even better exercise.

Comment: @Margon I am paginating at client side only but still the tbody only contains selected no of rows not all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Since your datatable use client side rendering, you can access to all your datas with this api -> [data()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/data())

simple usage from your fiddle

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({ 
    select: false,
    "columnDefs": [{
        className: "Name", 
        "targets":[0],
        "visible": false,
        "searchable":false
    }]
});//End of create main table

$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {

   alert(table.row( this ).data()[0]);

});

table.data().each(function(d){console.log(d)}) // this will print all your data
```